# Building a perl extension module on OpenBSD

Tags: perl, openbsd, perl-xs

How ought I build an XS perl module on OpenBSD when the requisite `.so` files are missing?

Background:   On a vanilla OpenBSD 5.3 vm install, I'm unable to build a perl module which needs to link against `-lpthread`.  pthread.a and pthread.so.Maj.Min *do* exist on the system.

However Makefile.PL is looking for `pthread.so`, which is absent.  Is this ordinary for OpenBSD?  (I can coerce the Makefile to link against pthread.a and things work just fine, as it happens.)

In a Redhat-ish Linux environment, I'd just install the right `-devel` RPM and go again.  On OpenBSD, however, I'm missing something very basic about the development environment.

**UPDATE** The core problem was Dynaloader mis-detection of libraries inside Makefile.PL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile is wrong, report the bug to the upstream. It never should look for a specific file. Look this example:

```
$ cat test.c              
int main(){
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -lpthread -o test test.c
$ ldd test
test:
    Start            End              Type Open Ref GrpRef Name
    00000c4321600000 00000c4321a02000 exe  1    0   0      test
    00000c4521f63000 00000c4522374000 rlib 0    2   0      /usr/lib/libpthread.so.17.1
    00000c4524c1c000 00000c4525103000 rlib 0    1   0      /usr/lib/libc.so.68.2
    00000c452a100000 00000c452a100000 rtld 0    1   0      /usr/libexec/ld.so
```

Also, in OpenBSD you don't need install a `-devel` package. OpenBSD has the batteries included.

Comment: Yes; something else was amiss — there was Dynaloader magic detection of libraries which is broken.  Close enough.

Answer (score 0):

While editing your Makefile.PL is one way to go, I generally see folks use link files to point generic library/executable names to version specific names.

```
For Example:
    pthread.so -> pthread.so.maj.min
    pthread.so.maj -> pthread.so.maj.min
```

This way things that want the 'latest' version can get it via the link & thinks that just care about major version can grab the most recent release of it's major version...

Comment: Right, but that can't be the standard practice for this kind of thing.  How would you dynamically compile a user program against pthread — make the right symlinks by hand every time?  That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Doesn't seem correct to me either.  I've usually seen it done by Distro Vendor/Package Author/Makefile.  Can't say if it's a great idea, just reporting what I've seen.